# SMTP Remote Queue on Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, smtp, remote, queue

We are currently using Windows Server 2003 R2 with Exchange 2003 and SolarWinds Exchange Monitor to monitor.

A couple of weeks ago the SMTP remote queue began to build up and it got to about 150 messages in the queue when it began to go down.

For the last couple of days the queue has been building up and it has now reached 450 messages.

Is there anyway that i can clear this and is it anything that I need to worry about?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can clear it (technically), but first I would find out why they are building up in the first place. They shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have the Mail Forwarder configured the following could be happening.

1. If you have Smart Forwarding via external host, that external host could be getting busy and throttling your connection with them.
2. If you are not using a Smart Forwarding host, the MX host accepting mail for the domain your trying to deliver mail to is not accepting mail, or is again, throttling your account
3. Your internal DNS server(s) is unable to resolve the external MX records correctly, ie, one server is setup to allowing forwarding but the other isn't configured to perform that function and depending on which DNS server your exchange SMTP server is using when it does the lookup, its unable to resolve the correct address and you start seeing a build up of mail.

Hope this helps.